# htaccess seo friendly urls for all subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

i have script in index.php in ALL folders

need to make pretty url/seo friendly urls like this: site.com/folder1/`something.html`

now i have ugly urls like this: site.com/folder1/`index.php?category=something`

this part `index.php?category=something` is always the same in all subfolders, i just want to change it to more seo friendly like `something.html`

once again: find `index.php?category=1$` and replace it with `1$.html`
do not touch anything else, just this part of url

so when i visit:

```
site.com/another-subfolder/and-one-more-folder-here/index.php?category=something
```

need to see this in address bar:

```
site.com/another-subfolder/and-one-more-folder-here/something.html
```

i hope you get it?

i tried this with `folder1` in htaccess in root

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*).html$ folder1/index.php?category=$1 [L,R=301]
```

ok this works, but how can i make this to work for all subfolders accross the site like this:

```
site.com/folder145/index.php?category=something
site.com/subfolder/index.php?category=something
site.com/another-subfolder/and-one-more-folder-here/index.php?category=something
```

there will be 1000s of subfolders with different names so manually making RewriteRule for each subfolder won't work

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change all the links that you generate from the `index.php?category=` form to the `category.html` form.

Then in the htaccess file in your document root, you add these rules to internally rewrite the `category.html` form back to the `index.php?category=` form:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?([^/]+)\.html$ /$1index.php?category=$2 [L]
```

Then, to point links you don't have any control over (or ones generated using a FORM) externally redirect any direct access to links in the `index.php?category=` form:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ (/.*?)?/index\.php\?category=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?index\.php$ /$1%3.html? [L,R=301]
```

This should match any and every subdirectory.

Comment: yessssssss finally it works, big thanks to you, i was trying to solve this mystery last few days but i couldn't do it, you're my savior :) this works exactly as i described!!! thanks again :)